# How to add mask on angular material date picker

Tags: angular

I recently started using angular material to build angular form in which i need to use angular material date picker but am not able to add any mask on the input element.

I want to allow the user only to be able to enter numbers and to format them in date format (MM/DD/YYYY) as he types in.

**html**:

```
<div class="example-container">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 required margin-top-ten">
    <mat-label>
      <span class="title">Date of Birth (MM/DD/YYYY)</span>  
    </mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker" formControlName="dateOfBirth" maxlength="10">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="myDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #myDatepicker></mat-datepicker>  
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Note:
I was trying to use **ngx-mask** and is not working on date picker only, on a regular text input like phone or fax fields is working just fine.

Comment: I think you want to use the moment date adapter or even write your own adapter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import * as textMask from 'vanilla-text-mask/dist/vanillaTextMask.js';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMaskDate]'
})
export class MaskDateDirective implements OnDestroy {

  mask = [/\d/, /\d/, '/', /\d/, /\d/, '/', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]; // dd/mm/yyyy
  maskedInputController;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
    this.maskedInputController = textMask.maskInput({
      inputElement: this.element.nativeElement,
      mask: this.mask
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.maskedInputController.destroy();
  }

}
```

use mask selector for the datepicker input

```
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dateOfBirth" #dateOfBirth appMaskDate>
```

Add subscription to the material datepicker own input

```
  eventSubscription: Subscription;
  @ViewChild('dateOfBirth') dateOfBirth: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild(MatDatepickerInput) datepickerInput: MatDatepickerInput<any>;
```

and on ngAfterViewInit

```
   this.eventSubscription = fromEvent(this.dateOfBirth.nativeElement, 'input').subscribe(_ => {
      this.datepickerInput._onInput(this.dateOfBirth.nativeElement.value);
    });
```

Comment: If  I want to use the two date pickers in the same component means. It is not properly working, for example, I am having two date pickers like From Date and To Date in a form, If I am editing the To Date after the From date , the To Date Value is appending to the From Date value. So, how can solve this issue?

Comment: @VigneshMohanraj The problem is @ViewChild(MatDatepickerInput) is too generic. Perhaps put an ID on the datepicker and use ViewChild by ID instead of using ViewChild by Component type.

Comment: Nice solution, thanks, I did have to add a 
// @ts-ignore
to 
import * as textMask from 'vanilla-text-mask/dist/vanillaTextMask.js';
to prevent compile errors though

Answer (score -3):

Check out the documentation below for sample use of datepicker.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular4-datepicker

1. Add a variable in the component

   ```
   myDatePickerOptions: IMyDpOptions = {
       // other options...
   dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yyyy'
   };
   ```
2. assign it to the input element.

   [options]="myDatePickerOptions"

Comment: The question is related to the Angular Material datepicker, and you have included a solution using a different library that is not compatible.