# Material Date Picker Mask with Form Control

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

When I am using Angular 6 Material Date Picker with any mask(ngx-mask, angular2-mask,angular2-text-mask) and use `formControlName`, I get an error:

> ERROR Error: More than one custom value accessor matches form control
>   with unspecified name attribute

Is there any mask that is working with Material Date Picker and `formControlName` attribute?

```html
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker" formControlName="dateOfbrd" mask="00/00/0000">
  <mat-error *ngFor="let validation of validationMessages.dateOfDischarge">
  <mat-error class="error-message" *ngIf=enrfrm.get('dateOfbrd').hasError(validation.type)">
    {{validation.message}}
  </mat-error>
</mat-error>
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="myDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #myDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
```

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51284664/how-to-add-mask-on-angular-material-date-picker

Answer (score 6):

The error is caused by `Datepicker` and `mask` attached to the same input. These components try to paralelly modify value stored in model.

One of possible solutions is having `Datepicker` attached to hidden input and `mask` on the visible one.

Comment: how would this work? I like the sound of it. Do you have an example?